# How to use .sf2 files in garageband?

Tags: garageband

I'm trying to get the soundfont from New Super Mario Bros. to work in garageband, because somebody ripped the midi files from the game. Except when I go to the Audio/MIDI tab, there aren't any instrument settings... [image: There's nothing under the Audio/MIDI tab.]

How can i fix this?

Comment: Do you have any MIDI devices you want to connect? Or are you just looking for a way to import a MIDI file into GarageBand?

Comment: Nope, I'm just trying to get the soundfont to work. I already have the midi files I'm trying to use but I don't know how to apply the soundfont.

Comment: Does https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/296101/how-to-use-soundfonts-in-garageband-10-2 help?