# Can't select a SoundFont instrument in GarageBand

Tags: finder, audio, garageband

I want to use the SGM SoundFont in GarageBand for my recreation.

However, when I try to load it onto my AUSampler, the dropdown menu next to Options > Instrument Name is greyed out and not clickable in my Finder window. Any clue why?

Here is a screenshot showing it:
[image]

I'm using GarageBand 10.3.5 on a MacBook Pro running Big Sur.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/296101/how-to-use-soundfonts-in-garageband-10-2

Comment: @Tetsujin I have already seen that post many times earlier. Unfortunately, it addressed a different problem where AUSampler does not show up in the plug-ins section.